# DataGrid Edit Problem

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have a DataGrid, with an ItemTemplate that has an image and label.  In the EditItemTemplate the label is replaced by a textbox.  My problem is that the edit template only shows when I click the Edit button the second time.  What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're re-binding the DataGrid after setting the EditItemIndex property.

Edit: Agreed with Massa. Best practice is to move your databinding into a separate method and call it first on the first page load, and again after setting EditItemIndex.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check for Page.IsPostback before binding your datagrid. It may be the case that you are binding during every page load.

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack() Then
    DoDataBinding()
End If
```